# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated resets contentOffset

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with my table view. When dismissing a modal view controller presented on top of it, it always scrolling to the top . I have tried observing the changes to `contentOffset` using KVO, but the one that messes my view goes behind it.

From the `UITableViewController`, when user finishes his task in the modal dialog, `self.tableView.contentOffset` is , I call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Subsequently, when the `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` is called, the `self.tableView.contentOffset` is already set to 0,0.

Is this supposed to be happening? I am able to work around the issue by remembering the scroll position before presenting the modal view and restore it back in viewWillAppear after dismissing the modal view. But it seems wrong. Am I missing something?

I have found similar problem described in [Dismiss modal view changes underlying UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168682/dismiss-modal-view-changes-underlying-uiscrollview).

Comment: can you check if `viewDidLoad:` gets called after dismissing the modal view? (I noticed this can happen during memory warning, some components are unloaded even if the view is pushed).

Comment: babbidi has a good point, your view could be unloaded while the modal view is on top, in the event of a memory warning.  If you initialize your table view in your viewDidLoad method, and there's a memory warning during the modal view, then the table view might be getting reinitialized when you dismiss the modal view.  Put NSLogs in viewDidUnload and viewDidLoad.

Comment: I was already monitoring `viewDidUnload` - and no, the view is not unloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is default behavior of UITableViewController. I tested it in very simple app and It worked exactly as you said. If you don't like it, use UIViewController instead.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion. I was beginning to question myself ;-)

Comment: @Split I have UIViewController but still this issue is reproducable

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I work around this problem, so that the table view maintains the original scroll position. In my subclass of `UITableViewController` I have added:

```
@property (assign) CGPoint lastScrollPosition;
```

Then in the implementation, I have overridden the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView.contentOffset = self.lastScrollPosition;
}

- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.lastScrollPosition = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    [super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```

If you want your table to initially appear scrolled to non-zero position, as I did, don't forget to initialize the `lastScrollPosition` in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks Palimondo for the post.  You solved an exact problem for me!